# How do I keep updating a variable after the user changes it in python?

Tags: python

I'm making a game where the user inputs "x" amount of chips to put in pile 1 and pile2. (eg. user input: 12; pile 1: 12, pile2: 12) and then takes away "z" amount of chips from the 1st pile or 2nd, and then after that the computer takes away the same amount of chips from the opposite pile that the user took from. So basically the computer wins all the time. But I'm having some trouble updating the piles until both piles reach 0.

```
def initGame():
    pile1= chips
    pile2= chips
    finished = False
    while chips<=0:
        if chips <= 0:
            print("Please input a number greater than 0")
        finished= True
    else:
        finished= True
    return pile1, pile2

def displayPiles(pile1, pile2):
    print("It is your turn human.")
    print("Here are the piles: ")
    print("pile 1: "+ str(pile1))
    print("pile 2: "+ str(pile2))

    return pile1, pile2

def getHumanMove(x,y):
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        x=int(input("Which pile would you like to take from?(1 or 2)"))
        y=int(input("How many would you like from pile "+ str(x)+ "? "))
        if pile1 and pile2<y:
            print("pile " +str(x)+ " does not have that many chips. Try again.")
        elif y==0:
            print("You must take at least one chip. Try again.")
        else:
            print("That was a legal move. Thank You.")
        finished = True
    return x,y

def getPiles(pile1, pile2, move):
    print("Here are the piles: ")
    x,y = move
    if x == 1:
        pile1= pile1- y
        print("pile 1: ", str(pile1))
        print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
    elif x == 2:
        pile2= pile1- y
        print("pile 1: ", str(pile1))
        print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
        return pile1, pile2

def getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2):
    print("Now it's my turn.")
    pile1, pile2= pile1, pile2
    x= x 
    y= y
    if x==1:
        print("I, the champion chips computer will take "+str(y)+ " chips from pile 2")
        pile2= pile2 - y
        pile1= pile1
    elif x==2:
        print("I, the champion chips computer will take "+str(y)+ " chips from pile 1")
        pile1= pile1 - y
        pile2= pile2
    if pile1==0 and pile2==0:
        print("The game is over because I took the last chip.")
        print("Thanks for playing. Let's wager next time.")        
    return x,y, pile1, pile2

def compPiles(pile1, pile2):
    print("Here are the piles: ")
    pile1, pile2= pile1, pile2
    print("pile 1: ", str(pile1))
    print("pile 2: ", str(pile2))
    return pile1, pile2
```

Main

```
chips = int(input("How many chips would you like to start with? "))

pile1, pile2= initGame()

display = displayPiles(pile1, pile2)

move= getHumanMove(pile1, pile2)

pile= getPiles(pile1, pile2, move)

x,y = move

_,_,pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2)

pile1, pile2 =pile1, pile2

compi= compPiles(pile1, pile2)
```

When I run this, it correctly takes away the number of chips being removed but then it doesn't update it when the computer makes a move.

```
Here are the piles: 
pile 1:  9
pile 2:  12
Now it's my turn.
I, the champion chips computer will take 3 chips from pile 2
Here are the piles: 
pile 1:  12
pile 2:  9
```

Comment: Easiest way is to use a list or a dictionary.

Comment: Why are you doing `pile1 = pile1` in your functions?

Comment: @lafexlos just a mistake. Just took it off.

Answer (score 0):

There's no surprise for the loss of update : you put the result of getCompMove in variable `pile` and never use it later. I think that if you add

```
pile1, pile2 = pile
```

or

```
pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(...)
```

it will perform better. By the way, as you are learning Python, you should try to convert all your separate functions into methods in a class that would contains the two piles : it would be clearer and you would have less variables to pass in and out. And systematicly hiding global variable with local of same name is à pain for the reader unless declared in a comment.